# Longest sequence of even numbers in python

Tags: python

Using non-library python code, how can i return the index and count of the longest sequence of even numbers?

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 8, 1]
```

should return 6 and 4, 6 being the index and 4 being the count. 
I tried without luck..

```
def evenSeq(list):
    count=0
    for i in list:
        if list[i]%2 and list[i+1]%2==0:
            count+=1
    return count
```

Comment: Add a bit extra information here. What is currently happening in your code that is not working to your expectation? What output are you currently getting for the input you are providing that is not meeting expectation?

Comment: An observation: what should happen to `count` if you run across an odd number?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh edited

Comment: Don't you want `for i, value in enumerate(list)`? Right now you're iterating through integers in a list and trying to use them as indices, which doesn't look like what you want to do. Doing it your way, you'd be hopping around the array, as opposed to iterating from beginning to end.

Comment: `count` is the length of the current sequence of even numbers.  When you see an odd number, you should reset `count`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye do you mean from `itertools.groupby`? If so I agree...

Comment: @MooingRawr Haha, for the love of `collections` I killed `itertools`. Yes that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```
def even_seq(l):
    best = (-1, -1)
    start_i = 0
    count = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(l):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
            if count > best[1]:
                best = (start_i, count)
        else:
            start_i = i + 1
            count = 0

    return best
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,3,2,6,4,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,8,1]
def evenSeq(a):
    largest = 0
    temp_largest = 0
    location = 0
    for count, value in enumerate(a):
        if value % 2 == 0:
            temp_largest += 1
        else:
            temp_largest = 0
        if temp_largest >= largest:
            largest = temp_largest
            location = count + 1 - temp_largest #plus one cause enumerate returns the index and we are subbing from the current streak which needs to be offset by one
    return location, largest

print(evenSeq(a)) #returns 2 8
```

Not the prettiest solution but it helps teaches you what's going on and the basic logic of the solution. Basically it checks if the number is even, and keeps a count on the current streak stored in `temp_largest`. Checks if the `temp_largest` is the biggest known streak at that moment, and updates the index from enumerate.

Edited based on comment:

```
for count, value in enumerate(a):
```

This line basically goes through the list, putting the value in `value` and the current index in `count`. `enumerate()` basically will go through what ever you pass it and returns a count starting from 0 along wit the item. see below for example.

```
a=[1,3,2,6,4,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,8,1]
for index, value in enumerate(a):
    print('{} index and value is {}'.format(index,value))
```

Prints out:

```
0 index and value is 1
1 index and value is 3
2 index and value is 2
3 index and value is 6
4 index and value is 4
5 index and value is 2
6 index and value is 2
7 index and value is 2
8 index and value is 2
9 index and value is 2
10 index and value is 1
11 index and value is 2
12 index and value is 2
13 index and value is 2
14 index and value is 8
15 index and value is 1
```

Comment: What does "for count, value in enumerate(a)" do?

Comment: Try it with this example: `evenSeq([4,4,4,1,2,2,2,2])`, it gives a wrong answer

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo oops missed an equal sign thanks for catching will update.

Comment: @MooingRawr Where did you miss the '='?

Comment: @SanderB sorry work was calling here's the final edit, if I'm still wrong/ there's bug sorry about it will update when I can.

Answer (score -1):

I would try it this way:

```
def evenSeq(seq):
    i = startindex = maxindex = maxcount = 0

    while i < len(seq):
        if seq[i]%2==0:
            startindex = i
            while i < len(seq) and seq[i]%2==0:
                i+=1
            if maxcount < i - startindex:
                maxcount = i - startindex
                maxindex = startindex            
        i+=1

    return (maxindex, maxcount)
```

Comment: Doesn't work, you are indexing based on the value and not the actual index.

Comment: You are using elements of the list as if they were indices.  Also, do not shadow the name of built in `list`